# Proper way to send an int64 over a socket in go

Tags: tcp, go

I'm trying to send a int64 over a TCP in golang, however, my receiver prints gets a different number then what I've sent out. What is the proper way to accomplish this?

```
//Buffer on both client and server
buffer := make([]byte, 1024)

//Sender
fileInfo, error := os.Stat(fileName)
if error != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error opening file")
}
var fSize int = int(fileInfo.Size())

connection.Write([]byte(string(fSize)))


//Receiver
connection.Read(buffer)

fileSize := new(big.Int).SetBytes(bytes.Trim(buffer, "\x00")).Int64()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("not a valid filesize")
    fileSize = 0
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [`binary.Write`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#Write) / [`binary.Read`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#Read):

```
//sender
err := binary.Write(connection, binary.LittleEndian, fileInfo.Size())
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("err:", err)
}

//receiver
var size int64
err := binary.Read(connection, binary.LittleEndian, &size)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("err:", err)
}
```

`[]byte(string(fSize))` doesn't do what you think it does, it treats the number as unicode character, it doesn't return the string representation of it.

If you want the string representation of a number, use [`strconv.Itoa`](http://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Itoa), if you want the binary represention then use:

```
num := make([]byte, 8) // or 4 for int32 or 2 for int16
binary.LittleEndian.PutUint64(num, 1<<64-1)
```

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? I answered almost 2 hours before @DewyBroto.

Comment: I'm new to this site, I don't think I down voted you... I clicked the checkmark. I just added a one up.

Also your solution worked for what I needed. :)

Comment: @DewyBroto No, just an example. `1<<64 - 1` is max uint64

Answer (score 1):

Use [binary.BigEndian](http://godoc.org/encoding/binary#BigEndian) or [binary.LittleEndian](http://godoc.org/encoding/binary#LittleEndian) to encode the integer:

```
  var size int64

  // Send

  var buf [8]byte
  binary.BigEndian.PutUint64(buf[:], uint64(size))
  _, err := w.Write(buf[:])

  // Receive

  var buf [8]byte
  _, err := io.ReadFull(r, buf[:])
  if err != nil {
      // handle error
  }
  size = int64(binary.BigEndian.Uint64(buf[:])
```

You can also use the [binary.Read](http://godoc.org/encoding/binary#Read) and [binary.Write](http://godoc.org/encoding/binary#Write). Your application code will be a little shorter at the cost of type switches and other goo inside these functions.

A couple of points about the code in the question. The conversion

```
 string(fSize)
```

returns the UTF-8 representation of the rune fSize. It does not return a decimal encoding or binary encoding the value. Use the [strconv](http://godoc.org/strconv) packate to convert a numeric value to a decimal representation. Use the above mentioned binary package to convert to binary representation.

The sequence

```
connection.Read(buffer)
buffer = bytes.Trim(buffer, "\x00")
```

trims away real data if the data happens to include a 0 byte at the ends. Read returns the number of bytes read. Use that length to slice the buffer:

```
n, err := connection.Read(buffer)
buffer = buffer[:n]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use string() to cast from an int, you need to use the [strconv](http://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#FormatInt) package.

```
connection.Write([]byte(strconv.FormatInt(fileInfo.Size(), 10))
```

Comment: While this works, it'd require more work to convert the string back to a number on the receiving side.